# Finding the area of the surface of a planar region

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the area of the surface bounded by the region $x+y+z=3a/2$, within the bounds of  $0≤x,y,z≤a$

What i tried

I first take the unit normal vector $n=1/3<1,1,1>$.I believe i must do an integral where the bounds are $x+y=a/2$ and $x+y=0$. However im unsure of how to proceed from here. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach that does not require integration: since $0\leq x,y,z \leq a$, the area is by definition included in a single octant. The equation is of the form $x+y+z=k$, which implies a planar surface. The intersections $A$, $B$, $C$ of the whole plane (not considering the bounds) with the three axes are given by points with coordinates $(\frac{3a}{2},0,0)$, $(0,\frac{3a}{2},0)$, and $(0,0,\frac{3a}{2})$. Also, the intersections with the planes $xy$, $xz$, and $yz$ are given by the lines that connect these points, with $45^o$ degree slopes. So, our area of interest is included in the triangle $ABC$, which is equilateral and whose side is $\frac{3\sqrt{2}a}{2}$.

Knowing this, and taking into account the bounds of $x,y,z$, it is not difficult to identify the resulting regular shape in the central portion of triangle $ABC$. To visualize it, simply trace, in the equilateral triangle, the three lines parallel to each side and whose distance from the parallel side is double than that from the corresponding opposite vertex (this corresponds to applying the bounds $0\leq x,y,z \leq a$ in our triangle). The area of the regular polygon obtained in this way can be easily calculated.

Comment: How did u arrive at the $45^o$ degree slopes and the side of  $\frac{3\sqrt{2}a}{2}$. Could u expalain. Thanks

Comment: Look at the $xy$ plane. The line connecting point $A$ with coordinates $(0,\frac{3a}{2})$ and point $B$ with coordinates $(\frac{3a}{2},0)$ creates an isosceles right triangle $ABO$ with the axes. So the length of $AB$ is $\frac {3a}{2} \sqrt{2}$. The same is valid for planes $xz$ and $yz$, and then for sides $BC$ and $AC$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: project the surface on the plane XY. Let be $D$ this projection. Parametrize the surface:
$$\Phi:D\longrightarrow\Bbb R^3$$
$$\Phi(x,y,z)=(x,y,?)$$
(what will be $z$?)
an apply the formula for the [area of a parametrized surface](http://mathinsight.org/parametrized_surface_area).

Comment: Is it necessary to use integration to evaluate the surface area. Can it be evaluated without having to go through integration?

Comment: In fact, isn't required because is simply a (regular) polygon and you can find easily the vertices. But you wrote "... do an *integral* where...".

Comment: How do i do it without integration. Could u explain please. Thanks

Comment: @yswong, see the anwer by Anatoly.

Comment: Actually this was just one of the steps of another question involving integrals, i managed to solve that question until i arrive at this point. Thanks for ur help though.